# How to call Node JS CLI command from web app?

Tags: node.js, web-applications, command-line-interface

I'm using this [Node JS script](https://github.com/karim0sec/Bulk-Tiktoks-Downloader) to scrap videos from tiktok. To use this script you have to run command via terminal.

Nothing done for the moment apart using the script via CLI as i'm still trying to figuring this out.

Now i'm wondering how could I could implement this into a webapp as UI.

I've been thinking

- installing the library on a webserver
- making an api to to communicate with this webserver to run the command.
- make my html/js or whatever to call the api

I dont if it's the best approach, i mean nodejs is supposed to be use from webserver  but i dont know anything about ..

Thanks

Comment: You could always extract the core code from the module, and replace all the data it requires from the CLI with your own variables, then set up a REST API to take params from the client and pass them into the core code